# Load csv.gz file containing both double quotes and comma with in a field string to Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a set of .csv.gz files that are to be loaded to my Snowflake table from S3 bucket. Problem is that, a particular field in the file has both double quotes and comma and hence I am unable to use FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"'.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please update your question to include sample data that illustrates the issue. However, it sounds like your file is not valid csv - if it’s not possible to reliably determine where a field starts and ends then you can’t process it

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but can you use another symbol to wrap the field instead? e.g. ^

Comment: If you can't request a new format for the file to be created, I have found it useful at times to load the entire record into a single string in Snowflake, and then use Snowflake to parse the string manually.  This gives you some more control over tricky fields that cause issues.  That said, I'd recommend requesting the file in a better structure.

Comment: @James Goodhand, thanks for your time though. It may sound stupid but that is how our clients are giving the raw data to us. We even tried explaining this to them and requested for a different delimiter or a file format but they denied as they take it from some API. Also please try to be gentle as we ourselves are struggling with these strange scenarios

Comment: @Rajalakshmi can you include an example line for us to work with? Can you also tell me how you as a human are identifying the delimitation between the different columns in the CSV?